# How to install node.js v16 on VPS cPanel WHM when ea-nodejs10 installs v10.24.1?

Tags: node.js, xrp

I want to `yum install xrpl` to sign transactions via the [xrpl.js](https://js.xrpl.org) library on a cPanel WHM VPS and have made it through [How to install a Node.js Application](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/) enough that all four ea-*** RPMs, including `ea-nodejs10` v10.24.1, have been installed. However, [xrpl.js](https://js.xrpl.org) recommends node.js v14 while also supporting v12 & v16.

Further, `package-lock.json` must be installed prior to `xrpl.js` - yet even though WHM Edit Package shows `package-lock.json` added:

[image]

`yum install package-lock.json` throws "No package package-lock.json available." Although repeating `yum install ea-nodejs10` returns "Package already installed."

So I would appreciate advice on how to install `node.js v14` and `package-lock.json` on this system thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now able to sign, send, and validate XRP Ledger transactions with `python` - hence my iOS-XRPL UI `javascript` brew will delegate its signing-validating to `python` functions.

Edit:
**MobileApp-XRP Ledger blockchain Linux dedicated server [xrpl-py](https://pypi.org/project/xrpl-py/) library installation**

MobileApp business XRPL transactions on `MoblieAppDomainName.com` browser requires a Dedicated Server, instead of a VPS, to install the required [xrpl-py](https://pypi.org/project/xrpl-py/) `python` library. Several guides continue to evolve for the several systems.

Present solution starts with [Bluehost Linux DS Python Installation latest version 3.9.2 guide](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/python-installation#download).

However the `make install` command attempts - and fails - to break the existing python 2.7 installation integral to the **cPanel** framework and needs to be replaced by `make altinstall` as described by [Grepitout: How to Install Python 3 in cPanel Server](https://grepitout.com/how-install-python-3-cpanel-server/).

Except that didn't quite work either -> What eventually worked on author's Mac OS-Linux system was [Computing for Geeks: Install Python 3.9 on CentOS 8 / CentOS 7 guide:](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-latest-python-on-centos-linux/)

```
$ ssh username@serveripaddress
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
sudo yum install openssl-devel libffi-devel bzip2-devel -y
$ gcc --version
sudo yum install wget -y
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.7/Python-3.9.7.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.9.7.tgz
cd Python-3.9*/
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
$ python3.9 --version
Python 3.9.7
```